# Setting up apache to view https pages

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, https

I am trying to set up a site using vmware workstation,  ubuntu 11.10, and apache2.  The site works fine but now the https pages are not showing up.  For example if I try to go to https://www.mysite.com/checkout I just see the message

> Not Found The requested URL /checkout/ was not found on this server.

I dont really know what I am doing and have tried a lot of things to get the ssl certificates in there right.

A few things I have in there, in my `httpd.conf` I just have :

`ServerName localhost`

In my `ports.conf` I have :

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
Listen 80

<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    # If you add NameVirtualHost *:443 here, you will also have to change
    # the VirtualHost statement in /etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl
    # to <VirtualHost *:443>
    # Server Name Indication for SSL named virtual hosts is currently not
    # supported by MSIE on Windows XP.
    Listen 443 http
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_gnutls.c>
    Listen 443 http
</IfModule>
```

In the /etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl :

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost _default_:443>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

        DocumentRoot /var/www
        <Directory />
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride None
        </Directory>
        <Directory /var/www/>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride None
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>

     .... truncated
```

in the sites-available/default I have :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

        DocumentRoot /var/www
        #DocumentRoot /home/magento/site/
        <Directory />
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride None
        </Directory>
        <Directory /var/www/>
        #<Directory /home/magento/site/>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride None
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all


        </Directory>

        ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
        <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
                AllowOverride None
                Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
        Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

        # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
        # alert, emerg.
        LogLevel warn

        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
    <Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
        Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
<virtualhost *:443>
  SSLEngine on
  SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/server.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/server.key
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
  <Directory />
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride None
        </Directory>
        <Directory /var/www/>
        #<Directory /home/magento/site/>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride None
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all


        </Directory>

</virtualhost>
```

I also have in sites-availabe a file setup for my site url, www.mysite.com so in /etc/apache2/sites-available/mysite.com

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName mysite.com
        DocumentRoot /home/magento/mysite.com

        <Directory />
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride All
        </Directory>
        <Directory /home/magento/mysite.com/ >
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog /home/magento/logs/apache.log

        # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
        # alert, emerg.
        LogLevel warn
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerName mysite.com
   DocumentRoot /home/magento/mysite.com

        <Directory />
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride All
        </Directory>
        <Directory /home/magento/mysite.com/ >
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog /home/magento/logs/apache.log

        # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
        # alert, emerg.
        LogLevel warn
</VirtualHost>
```

Thanks for any help getting this setup!  As is probably obvious from this post I am pretty lost at this point.

Comment: can you open http://www.mysite.com/checkout on port 80 without any issues ?

Comment: yes, i disabled the secure pages from the magento app I am running and the pages load fine.

Answer (score 2):

A couple of things you can try:

1. Since you're using `<VirtualHost *:443>` in `/etc/apache2/sites-available/mysite.com`, replace both instances of `Listen 443 http` with

   ```
   NameVirtualHost *:443
   Listen 443
   ```

   in your `ports.conf`.
2. As far as I can tell, you are not using the default configurations to actually serve a website.

   If I'm right, disable them:

   ```
   a2dissite default default-ssl
   ```

   In this case, you should also delete the line

   ```
   ServerName localhost
   ```

   from your `httpd.conf`.
3. Make sure your newest configuration and SSL are enabled.

   ```
   a2ensite mysite.com
   a2enmod ssl
   ```
4. After making any changes, remember to reload apache to activate the new configuration:

   ```
   service apache2 reload
   ```

Comment: Thanks, I followed everything but now I get a SSL connection error when I try to go to https://  Also when I restart apache2 I see errors like `[warn] NameVirtualHost *:443 has no VirtualHosts `

Comment: I am also seeing this error : `VirtualHost *:443 -- mixing * ports and non-* ports with a NameVirtualHost address is not supported, proceeding with undefined results`

Comment: Try removing the `NameVirtualHost *:443` lines.

Comment: hmm i tried and it was still giving me those errors.  I removed /conf.d/virtual.conf and error went away, but now I am back to a 404 on https pages

Comment: What do the log files say? Also, apache might not even be the culprit. This could have something to do with vmware.

Comment: ack.. hmm this sux. Logs no help... I dont think.. it does say client denied by server configuration (the local.xml of this magento install) but I dont think that is it

Answer (score 0):

below part does not seem to be correct

this is a virtual host for ssl connections on 443,

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost _default_:443>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

        DocumentRoot /var/www
        <Directory />
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride None
        </Directory>
        <Directory /var/www/>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride None
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>
```

you are receiveing error due to inappropriate

```
DocumentRoot /var/www
```

change it to the same values as in

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
```